# javascript xml rpc server

Tags: javascript, xml-rpc

I am looking to implement a javascript application which will get has to run XML- RPC  server .I have tried searched a bit Javascript XML-RPC CLIENT can be implemented  but  Is it possible to implement a **Javascript xml-rpc server** ???

Comment: You mean, in server-side JavaScript? Or in the browser? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I am looking for running Javascript XML RPC server in the browser

Comment: What for? Who would call that server?

Comment: i am just searching if it is possible or not , if yes how .But anyway idea was dat the javascript would connect to an agent in cloud now i have decided to go  for it using Ajax and run a php xml -rpc server whose service would be called by Agent in the cloud